# SAPUI5: When I add custom columns to smart table they don't show in filter tab

Tags: annotations, odata, sapui5

I want to use smart table with a named model. If we use a named model then it does not show the data. One possibility is to use custom list and custom columns. But as soon as I use the custom List it shows data but it will remove the defined custom columns from the "Filter, Group and sort" tabs. It means in the P13N dialog you can just play with the position of columns (As soon as you define the custom columns for all fields it will remove the "Filter, Group and sort" tabs from the P13N dialog).

I need to use named model because of some reasons. Then I need to use custom list items and columns. Now the question is how I can keep these fields or columns in the filtering, sorting and grouping tabs in P13N dialog.

```
<smartTable:SmartTable id="__smartTableMlst" entitySet="ProjectHeaderMstSet" tableBindingPath="TableMlstJsonModel>/ProjectHeaderMstSet"
header="{i18n>tableMlstTitle}" showRowCount="true" tableType="Responsive" showFullScreenButton="false" useVariantManagement="false"
enableAutoBinding="true" ignoredFields="ProjectDefinition,Method,Refnumber" useExportToExcel="false"
initiallyVisibleFields="MilestoneNumber,Description,OffsetMilestoneDate,OffsetMilestoneDateUnit">
<smartTable:customToolbar>
    <m:OverflowToolbar design="Transparent">
        <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
        <m:Button type="Transparent" press="onRefreshMlstBtnPress" icon="sap-icon://refresh" tooltip="{i18n>refreshBtnTooltip}"/>
        <m:Button type="Transparent" press="onAddMlstBtnPress" icon="sap-icon://add" tooltip="{i18n>createBtnTooltip}"
            enabled="{objectView>/tableMlstBtnAddEnabledFinal}"/>
        <m:Button type="Transparent" press="onDeleteMlstBtnPress" icon="sap-icon://delete" tooltip="{i18n>deleteBtnTooltip}"
            enabled="{objectView>/tableMlstBtnDelEnabledFinal}"/>
    </m:OverflowToolbar>
</smartTable:customToolbar>
<m:Table id="tableMlst" mode="MultiSelect" busy="{objectView>/tableMlstBusy}">
    <m:columns>
        <m:Column>
            <m:customData>
                <core:CustomData key="p13nData" value='\{"columnKey": "MilestoneNumber", "leadingProperty": "MilestoneNumber"}'/>
            </m:customData>
            <m:Text text="{/#ProjectHeaderMst/MilestoneNumber/@sap:label}"/>
        </m:Column>
    </m:columns>
    <m:items>
        <m:ColumnListItem type="Navigation" press="onPress">
            <m:cells>
                <m:Text text="{path: 'TableMlstJsonModel>MilestoneNumber', formatter: '.formatter.intNumber'}"/>
                <m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>Description}"/>
                <m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>OffsetMilestoneDate}"/>
                <m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>OffsetMilestoneDateUnit}"/>
                <m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>Activity}"/>
                <m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>ActivityName}"/>
                <m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>Aedat}"/>
                <m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>Aenam}"/>
                <m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>Erdat}"/>
                <m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>Ernam}"/>
                <m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>MlstSmlnr}"/>
                <m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>Network}"/>
                <m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>NetworkName}"/>
            </m:cells>
        </m:ColumnListItem>
    </m:items>
</m:Table>
</smartTable:SmartTable>
```

I know about the usage of annotation files in smart tables, but is it possible to use annotation files with named JSON models? In the following image You can see how the MilestoneNumber has been removed from the filter list.

[image: You can see how the MilestoneNumber has been removed from the filter list]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pass `filterProperty` and `sortProperty` in custom column. You even can play with the starting position of the column or its visibility.

these are the key points of your answer

I added them for two columns of your code. Be aware by defining the columns, the property, `initiallyVisibleFields` will be ignored. Then you need to pass the visibility of the `Column` like this:

Here is modified code:

```
    <smartTable:SmartTable id="__smartTableMlst" entitySet="ProjectHeaderMstSet" tableBindingPath="TableMlstJsonModel>/ProjectHeaderMstSet"
header="{i18n>tableMlstTitle}" showRowCount="true" tableType="Responsive" showFullScreenButton="false" useVariantManagement="false"
enableAutoBinding="true" ignoredFields="ProjectDefinition,Method,Refnumber" useExportToExcel="false">
<smartTable:customToolbar>
<m:OverflowToolbar design="Transparent">
<m:ToolbarSpacer/>
<m:Button type="Transparent" press="onRefreshMlstBtnPress" icon="sap-icon://refresh" tooltip="{i18n>refreshBtnTooltip}"/>
<m:Button type="Transparent" press="onAddMlstBtnPress" icon="sap-icon://add" tooltip="{i18n>createBtnTooltip}"
enabled="{objectView>/tableMlstBtnAddEnabledFinal}"/>
<m:Button type="Transparent" press="onDeleteMlstBtnPress" icon="sap-icon://delete" tooltip="{i18n>deleteBtnTooltip}"
enabled="{objectView>/tableMlstBtnDelEnabledFinal}"/>
</m:OverflowToolbar>
</smartTable:customToolbar>
<m:Table id="tableMlst" mode="MultiSelect" busy="{objectView>/tableMlstBusy}">
<m:columns>
<m:Column visible="true">
<m:customData >
<core:CustomData key="p13nData" value='\{"sortProperty": "MilestoneNumber", "filterProperty": "MilestoneNumber", "columnKey": "MilestoneNumber", "leadingProperty": "MilestoneNumber", "columnIndex":"0"}'/>
</m:customData>
<m:Text text="{/#ProjectHeaderMst/MilestoneNumber/@sap:label}"/>
</m:Column>
<m:Column visible="false">
<m:customData>
<core:CustomData key="p13nData" value='\{"sortProperty": "Description", "filterProperty": "Description", "columnKey": "Description", "leadingProperty": "Description", "columnIndex":"1"}'/>
</m:customData>
<m:Text text="{/#ProjectHeaderMst/Description/@sap:label}"/>
</m:Column>
</m:columns>
<m:items>
<m:ColumnListItem type="Navigation" press="onPress">
<m:cells>
<m:Text text="{path: 'TableMlstJsonModel>MilestoneNumber', formatter: '.formatter.intNumber'}"/>
<m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>Description}"/>
<m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>OffsetMilestoneDate}"/>
<m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>OffsetMilestoneDateUnit}"/>
<m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>Activity}"/>
<m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>ActivityName}"/>
<m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>Aedat}"/>
<m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>Aenam}"/>
<m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>Erdat}"/>
<m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>Ernam}"/>
<m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>MlstSmlnr}"/>
<m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>Network}"/>
<m:Text text="{TableMlstJsonModel>NetworkName}"/>
</m:cells>
</m:ColumnListItem>
</m:items>
</m:Table>
</smartTable:SmartTable>
```

have fun